# Is SSH enabled by default on Ubuntu recovery mode?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh

I have a few servers at home running Ubuntu headless, and one of them (that runs my reverse proxy and therefore access to the rest of my services) is connected to multiple external drive docks. I know this is a bad setup, but it's what I have right now. Currently, when I have a power outage, those docks don't come back on automatically and my server refuses to boot as I have them all listed in the fstab file. It does, however, boot directly into recovery mode when it's unable to connect to those external drives. Is SSH enabled by default in recovery mode? I've been unable to connect to it for hours/days at a time when I'm not able to get to my rack and turn the drive docks back on, and for some reason can't SSH into it in recovery mode. Is this something I'm able to turn on, or should it be working by default?